# Editor and Designer are gone from Office 365 WordApp

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

When I open any document (stored in OneDrive) in browser (Office 365) then I can clearly see that I have Editor and Designer functionalities available:

[image]

When I open the very same document in Office 365 WordApp these functionalities are gone:

[image]

What I managed to check or do so far is:

- I am using "English (United States)" dictionary, so [no Chinese language](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-editor-not-showing-in-word/560bf7cb-b7fb-4ad4-bc06-88c7cf526c4a)
- I have installed all the updates available to Office
- I have used both "Quick Repair" and "Online Repair" options on "Add or remove programs" applet.

What else can I do in order to get Editor to my offline / desktop version of Microsoft Word 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer is the Browser version of the Design Tab which has far more options.
The Editor should be available on the Home Tab and is also available on the Review Tab.

I see in your screenshot a **Reuse** button. This is not part of the general release of Word. It may be from an Add-In. Try [opening Word is safe mode](https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) and seeing if the Editor appears on the Home Tab as well. If so, the absence on the Home tab when you start Word regularly is likely due to an Add-In, perhaps the same one.

Comment: The "Editor" button has finally "returned" to my Word after several runs after repairing the entire Office package. The "Browse" button never returned and shouldn't return, as you explained this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look and my Word 365 got all the features you say are missing.
[image]

Designer is under the tab Design and the Editor is both under Review and Home where you say it's missing.

Please have another look and mark this as answer if you could find it.

Further information:

Of course there will always be a difference between the local version and the web version. However afaik all the features should be always available but might be listed in a different tab or with a different name. 
I use the following version. I doubt that 32-Bit and 64-bit will be much different in the available features.
Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20118) 32-bit

Comment: The "Editor" button has finally "returned" to my Word after several runs after repairing the entire Office package. The "Browse" button never returned for the reasons explained in [Charles Kenyon's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1709206/156554). For this reason I can only up-vote your answer, but I am going to accept the other one as it is more accurate, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the bar (where the autosave switch is)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6Ms.png), where it says "customize quick actions," click on the three dots "..." and click on "editor" and the editor panel button will pop up!

Comment: Welcome to the society. Thanks for contributing, but unfortunately your answer is off-topic. The question deals with **browser** version of Word 365 while your screen clearly shows **desktop application**.